# Select the cheapest price and then group it by the vendor?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase

I want to provide the technical purchasing team with a default supplier setting to let them know where to order a part. This is based on a table called price_book. For this I need a new table with the partnumber, the cheapest price and the supplier code to process it through the system. How can I select only the supplier who is providing the cheapest price?

I'm doing this to simplify the ordering process for the technical pruchasing team. I've come so far that I only have the cheapest price per supplier (regarding minimum order quantity). What piece I'm missing is the part that only one supplier with the cheapest price is selected. So per partnumber the cheapest price with the corresponding supplier.

The query is quite short:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pb.partno, MIN(pb.purch_price * c.rate) AS 'cheapest_price', pb.supplier
FROM price_book pb
LEFT JOIN currency c ON c.currency = pb.currency
WHERE pb.contract_id <> 0
AND pb.expire_date > Datediff(Day, '31 Dec 1971', Getdate())
AND pb.order_type = 'P'
AND pb.condition = 'N'
GROUP BY partno, supplier
```

The WHERE clause is not important as it has to do with internal processes.

The outcome should be a list with the columns partnumber, price and corresponding supplier. Per partnumber there should be only the cheapest price with the supplier.

Comment: Any SELECT in the query?

Comment: Ohh sorry! Just added the SELECT statement

Answer (score 0):

Try `TOP(1) WITH TIES`

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES pb.partno, pb.purch_price * c.rate [cheapest_price], pb.supplier
FROM price_book pb
LEFT JOIN currency c ON c.currency = pb.currency
WHERE pb.contract_id <> 0
AND pb.expire_date > Datediff(Day, '31 Dec 1971', Getdate())
AND pb.order_type = 'P'
AND pb.condition = 'N'
ORDER BY row_number() over(partition by partno order by pb.purch_price * c.rate [cheapest_price] desc);
```

Comment: T-SQL server does not recognize the WITH TIES statement. The message which pops up is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'"

Comment: @dominic.landert , tag dbms properly. This answer is for ms sql server currently supported versions.

Comment: I asked the system responsible and he assured me it is T-SQL.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 `TOP(1) WITH TIES` is supported since 2008. What is your version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try windows function for this purpose, the code would be similar to the below example

Note - The code is not tested.

```
SELECT * from
(SELECT pb.partno,pb.supplier,pb.purch_price * c.rate as price, 
row_number() over(partition by pb.partno,pb.supplier order by pb.purch_price * c.rate )rn
FROM price_book pb
LEFT JOIN currency c ON c.currency = pb.currency
WHERE pb.contract_id <> 0
AND pb.expire_date > Datediff(Day, '31 Dec 1971', Getdate())
AND pb.order_type = 'P'
AND pb.condition = 'N')a
where a.rn=1
```

Comment: My SQL server does not recognize the OVER statement. The message which pops up is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'"

Comment: You mean MSSQL?

Comment: We're using T-SQL in the company. And it is not in a Windows application but a very specific aviation software.

Comment: TSQL, supports over clause.

Comment: your error message is stating MY SQL, so the server that you are mentioning is wrong, you are not using TSQL you are using My SQL. My SQL does not have over clause as far as I know. you should change the tag in question to My SQL

Comment: I just asked the system responsibles and they told me it is definitly T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

```
DECLARE @priceBook TABLE (PriceID       INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
,                         PartNo        NVARCHAR(10)
,                         Price         DECIMAL(18, 2)
,                         fk_SupplierID INT);

INSERT INTO @priceBook (PartNo, Price, fk_SupplierID)
VALUES (N'123', 8.99, 1)
,      (N'123', 9.99, 2)
,      (N'456', 10.99, 1)
,      (N'456', 3.99, 2)
,      (N'456', 12.99, 3);

WITH cte AS
    (SELECT PriceID
     ,      PartNo
     ,      Price
     ,      fk_SupplierID
     ,      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartNo
ORDER BY Price ASC) RN
       FROM @priceBook)
SELECT  cte.PriceID
,       cte.PartNo
,       cte.Price
,       cte.fk_SupplierID
  FROM  cte
 WHERE  rn = 1;
```

It's a basic example of the windowing functionality mentioned above.  This does run on MS SQL Server, not sure about mySQL.  Give it a test and if it does work for you then you can adjust for your exact structure.

Comment: Here I get an error message saying "A batch has to begin with a select/update/insert/delete-command"

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using mySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: According to the system administrator we are using T-SQL

Comment: T-SQL is the language - what we are looking for is the server type.  T-SQL implies Microsoft SQL Server, but your error messages are suggesting something else.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but is it SYBASE DBMS 15.7?

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for - but not the answer I was hoping for. For future reference Sybase is not the same as Microsofts SQL-Server, which explains why your having difficulty with your answers.  Sybase would have been a better tag, and would have yielded responses more specific to your system.  While there are a lot of similarities they are not the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: I will consider it for my next qustion. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

I found now a code which works for me:

```
SELECT B.partno,
MAX(C.supplier) AS supplier
FROM

(SELECT A.partno,
MIN(A.price) AS price
FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT pb.partno AS partno, MIN(pb.purch_price * c.rate) AS price, pb.supplier AS supplier
FROM price_book pb
LEFT JOIN currency c ON c.currency = pb.currency
LEFT JOIN part p ON p.partno = pb.partno
WHERE pb.contract_id <> 0
AND pb.expire_date > Datediff(Day, '31 Dec 1971', Getdate())
AND pb.order_type = 'P'
AND pb.condition = 'N'
AND p.mat_class IN ('C', 'E')
GROUP BY pb.partno, supplier) A

GROUP BY A.partno) B

JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT pb.partno AS partno, MIN(pb.purch_price * c.rate) AS price, pb.supplier AS supplier
FROM price_book pb
LEFT JOIN currency c ON c.currency = pb.currency
LEFT JOIN part p ON p.partno = pb.partno
WHERE pb.contract_id <> 0
AND pb.expire_date > Datediff(Day, '31 Dec 1971', Getdate())
AND pb.order_type = 'P'
AND pb.condition = 'N'
AND p.mat_class IN ('E', 'C')
GROUP BY pb.partno, supplier) C ON B.partno=C.partno and B.price=C.price
GROUP BY B.partno
```

Thank you very much for the support you gave me guys!!

Cheers,
Dominic